# setting a default apache virtual host

Tags: apache

Is there any better way of setting the default apache virtual host other than it just picking the first config it finds?

I have a server with many domains, of which only some are configured with httpd but the default virtual host severed up is for example is aaa.com where as really I would like it to default to mmm.com instead?

Something like parking domains without going through the hassle of setting up a config for each one - then I can serve a "content this domain has not been created yet" page?

Cheers

Comment: I am tryingt to change the default ssl virtualhost. /etc/httpd/conf.d/e.conf is overriding ssl.conf, this makes sense as it's processed alphabetically. What doesn't make sense is that before ssl.conf got processed first, HOW CAN I GET SSL.conf processed first like before I installed letsencryp

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/1013276/568819

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a default virtual host and name it something like `000-default` so that it loads first and is used unless another vhost matching the requested domain is found. Here's the bare-bones `000-default`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory /var/www >
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you can setup a PHP file under `/var/www` to create a domain parking page (this is a very simplified example):

```
<?php

printf('The domain <b>%s</b> is being parked', 
    htmlentities($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));

?>
```

Comment: Had some issues with the name `000-default`: ERROR: Site default does not exist! Changing to `default` made it run smooth. Thanks!

Comment: I am tryingt to change the default ssl virtualhost.    /etc/httpd/conf.d/e.conf is overriding ssl.conf, this makes sense as it's processed alphabetically. What doesn't make sense is that before ssl.conf got processed first, HOW CAN I GET SSL.conf processed first like before I installed letsencrypt

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/789050/apache-2-4-ssl-default-overriding-virtualhost/1013276#1013276

Answer (score 1):

The first ***sites-available*** conf file is default (alphabetically).  There should be a **000-default.conf** file already, if not create it.

Edit this one to your liking and then make sure it's enabled ***a2ensite 000-default.conf***. And apache2 is reloaded ***sudo service apache2 reload***.

Then any request that isn't caught by your other vhosts will come here.

Comment: Super important to enable using a2ensite 000-default.conf command. Doesn't work unless you actually run this and run sudo service apache2 reload. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use ServerAlias in a name-based VirtualHost, you will only have to add one line per each new domain.