# How to allow phpmyadmin accessible from only ip address?

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, vps, ubuntu-13.10

I have a VPS server from digitalocean. It is running on ubuntu 13.10 64 bit o with apache 2.4, PHP 5 and mysql 5.5

I've installed phpmyadmin. I want to access it through only ip address. I mean `12.34.56.789/pma`

but the thing is that I've set up two virtual hosts domain and www.domain so if I go to `domain/pma` and `www.domain/pma` it allows me to access phpmyadmin which I don't want to allow. So any suggestion friends? Here is my `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` file's codes.

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration

Alias /pma /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
```

So how to allow access to phpmyadmin from only ip address?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a default Virtual Host directive. You can follow this link : [setting a default apache virtual host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858459/setting-a-default-apache-virtual-host)
2. Put your alias /pma into the default virtual host. It might look like:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot /var/www
       <Directory /var/www >
           AllowOverride All
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
       </Directory>

       Alias /pma /usr/share/phpmyadmin

       <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
           Options FollowSymLinks
           DirectoryIndex index.php
           AllowOverride All
       </Directory>

   </VirtualHost>
   ```